# Send mail with an attachment and body of mail with table format

Tags: linux, sendmail

I need to send a mail with an attachment and body of mail in table format.I have used the below code to send mail. but unable to attache file.

```
 (echo "From: ";    
  echo "Subject: testing of table using awk";  
  echo "Content-type: text/html";    
  echo;     
  awk 'BEGIN{print "<table>"} {print "<tr><tr>";for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print "<td><td>" $i"</td></td>";print  "</tr></tr>"} END{print "</table>"}' input1.txt;
 ) | sendmail xxx@yyy.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sendmail`:

```
TO_ADDRESS="abc@example.com"
SUBJECT="Test Mail"

cat << --OEF--
Subject: $SUBJECT
TO: $TO_ADDRESS
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="MAIL_BOUNDARY"


--MAIL_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="MAIL_BOUNDARY2"

--MAIL_BOUNDARY2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

$SUBJECT

--MAIL_BOUNDARY2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

--OEF--
cat MailBody.html 

cat << --OEF--

--MAIL_BOUNDARY2--

--MAIL_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/zip; name=file.zip
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

--OEF--
base64  /opt/file.zip
cat << --OEF--

--MAIL_BOUNDARY--
--OEF--
) |  /usr/sbin/sendmail $TO_ADDRESS
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a version of `mail` command supporting `-a` (attachment) switch . It's the more reliable solution.

[s-nail](http://www.sdaoden.eu/code.html#s-nail) have it !

```
email=foo@base

mail -v -s subject foo@bar -a file.txt -q - <<EOF 
$(awk '
    BEGIN{print "<table>"}
    {
        print "<tr><tr>";
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            print "<td><td>" $i"</td></td>";
            print  "</tr></tr>";
        }
    }
    END{print "</table>"}' input1.txt
)

.
EOF
```

Check `man mail` if you need to add headers and such

Comment: i need body of mail with table format as well...

Comment: mail command is not converting to table format. it is  printing with html tags..

Comment: Sure, you need to read the `man mail` to add headers as already said