# convert my csv file output to html table with heading bold and and send email using post fix & also want to change the font to calibri

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, suse

```
for i in $(cat HPE_FRAMES_IP); do ssh Reports@$i showsys | awk '{print $2","$5}' ; ssh Reports@$i showpd -degraded -failed | awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$5}' ; done | grep -v "MiB" | grep -v "total" | egrep -B3 "failed|degraded" | sed 's/---Name/\n---Name/g'| sed 's/-//g'

Name,Nodes
CR3HP8401,2M263601BJ
Id,CagePos,Type,State
175,9:15:0,FC,failed


Name,Nodes
FM1HP20841,CZ3741X5K8
Id,CagePos,Type,State
18,4:2:0,SSD,degraded
```

Desired output:

```
Name,Nodes                bold and calibri
CR3HP8401,2M263601BJ      calibri
Id,CagePos,Type,State     bold and calibri  
175,9:15:0,FC,failed      calibri
```

Comment: take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444212/270935

Comment: What attempts have you made to convert your text to html?

Comment: I tried pasting my csv output in an internet website where it converts to html code. i tried to cat that html and sent an, my email shows only the html code not actual table