# Is there any way to send the html mail in email body and a csv file as an attachment in linux

Tags: awk, email, sendmail

Please see my below snippet, it is ignoring the attachment, only displaying the HTML content in the email body. I want to attach CSV file with it. Thanks in advance!!

```
awk -F ','  '
        BEGIN {

                print "From: xyz@gmail.com"
                print "To: abc@gmail.com"
                print "MIME-Version: 1.0"
                print "Content-Type: text/html"
                print "Subject: Weekly DM Row Count Sheet and Unmatched Data"
                print "<html><body><font face=verdana size=2 color=black ></br></br>Hi Team, </br>Please find the Weekly DM Row Count Sheet and Unmatched Data details. </br></br> <B> Row count is not matching for below tables. Please look into it.</b></br></br> "
                print "<table border=1 cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 height="75">"
        }
        !/^#/ && /^S/ {
                print "<tr>"
                for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
                        print "<td> <center> <font face=verdana size=2> " $i " </center></td>"
                print "</tr>"
        }
        !/^#/ && !/^S/ {
                print "<tr>"
                for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
                        print "<td> <center> <font face=verdana size=2> " $i " </center></td>"
                print "</tr>"
        }
        END {
print "</table>" print "</br></br></b> Thanks & Regards</br> MS Support Team</br>"
print "</body></html>"
} ' NO_MATCH.csv | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t uuencode /root/ms_dba_admin/Scripts/PROMPT_AUDIT_ORDER/temp.csv
```

Comment: [Related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444212/270935)

Comment: Hi, I saw the related article, but that did not help. It is showing the code in email body and it is not attaching the file in email.

Comment: it has an attachment `file.zip`

Comment: I am getting HTMLcode in the email body instead of an attachment.

Comment: You'll need to format the message as a MIME email. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17359/7552 for some examples.

Comment: Thanks!! code is working for me, but I am facing one issue, it is supporting a HTML file with a blank line at the beginning and the end. If the HTML file doesn't contain the blank line, it is making email body blank instead of HTML content in it.